# How to get the date of a given day in a specific week?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to get date of specific day of a given week. The week is decided by the entered date.

For example, if I want the Friday of these dates:

1. `06/27/2018`
2. `07/04/2018`
3. `07/07/2018`

I expect as outcome:

1. `06/29/2018`
2. `07/06/2018`
3. `07/06/2018`

Here, week is defined as Monday to Sunday.

Comment: How do you define a "week"? Sunday to Saturday? Monday to Sunday?

Comment: @DavidG Week define on the base of date pass by user. I have given 3 example in question. Please let me know in case any query.

Comment: You misunderstand. If I give you 8th July, is the Friday for that day going to be 6th or 13th? Because some cultures consider Sunday to be the start of a week and others consider it to be the end.

Comment: @DavidG It should consider week from Monday to Sunday. So, it should be 6th july. Please let me know if any other query. I will explain in detail if more details required. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification of the current version of DavidG's answer:

```
static DateTime GetDay(DateTime source, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  const int offsetSinceMondayIsFirstDayOfWeek = 7 - (int)DayOfWeek.Monday;
  return source.AddDays(((int)dayOfWeek + offsetSinceMondayIsFirstDayOfWeek) % 7
    - ((int)source.DayOfWeek + offsetSinceMondayIsFirstDayOfWeek) % 7);
}
```

This takes into account that the asker considers Monday to be the first day of the week. If you want Saturday as the first day of week, just replace `Monday` with `Saturday` above.

In the special case where you consider Sunday the first day of the week, it reduces to DavidG's original method:

```
static DateTime GetDay(DateTime source, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  return source.AddDays((int)dayOfWeek - (int)source.DayOfWeek);
}
```

because the `DayOfWeek` enum type of the BCL already "wraps around" between `Saturday` (`= 6`) and `Sunday` (`= 0`).

---

On http://chartsbin.com/view/41671 there is a world map that apparently shows what day of week is considered the first day of the week in different regions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with some clever maths based on the `DayOfWeek`:

```
public DateTime GetDay(DateTime source, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, 
    DayOfWeek weekStartsOn = DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    var offset = (int)source.DayOfWeek - (int)weekStartsOn;;
    if(offset < 0)
    {
        offset = offset + 7;
    }
    return source.AddDays(-offset + (int)dayOfWeek - (int)weekStartsOn);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var someDate = ...; //Get a date from somewhere

var friday = GetDay(someDate, DayOfWeek.Friday);
var monday = GetDay(someDate, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

And if your week starts on a Sunday, just use the optional third parameter, for example:

```
var friday = GetDay(someDate, DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: The `DayOfWeek` enum type "wraps around" between `Saturday` (`= 6`) and `Sunday` (`= 0`). This may not be what the asker wants (cf. your own comments to him). So will it be _the right_ Friday if I do `GetDay(new DateTime(2018, 7, 8), DayOfWeek.Friday)`?

Comment: I just posted a kind of fix, in a separat answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void TestMethod1 ( )
    {

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime friday = date.AddDays( (int)DayOfWeek.Friday - (int)date.DayOfWeek );
        Console.WriteLine( friday.ToString( ) );

    }
```

Comment: This does not take into account that the asker considers Monday to be the first day of week (see comments to question). So if now `date` is 2018 July 08 (Sunday), you will add positive five days, but the asker wants negative two in that case, i.e. the asker wants 2018 July 06 (Friday).

Answer (score -4):

```
   using System;
      using System.Globalization;

   public class Example
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
         Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ddd", 
                           new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));    
      }
   }
```

Comment: How does this give you a Friday?!

Comment: if you have a better solution to help, then post it buddy

Comment: I will when OP answers the question I asked.

Comment: I suggest to read question more carefully. In real, Friday will not be fix. It is just an example.

Comment: This doesn't answer any question, and in any case, why would the OP want to print a hard-coded date in french? Please read [answer]